# 'No such table' error in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm a complete beginner to SQLite. I'm trying to open a database called `CollegeData`. `CollegeData.sql` is in the same directory as `sqlite3.exe`.In sqlite3 I'm typing in:

```
_.read CollegeData.sql_
```

Then I get an error for every line:

```
_near line #no.: no such table: #table name_
```

If I try:

```
_.open CollegeData.sql_
```

and then run a query, I get info that `CollegeData is not a database`.

Please help!

Comment: Does the .sql file contain only queries (e.g. select soemthing from sometable;``) or does it also contain lines which set a database up (e.g. `create table tname (....)` )? If you want to run queries, you first need database content. You might benefit from an SQLite tutorial. Have you select one and worked through it?

Comment: A common habit for naming databases is "*.db". Is there such a file somewhere in your environment?

Comment: What is the origin of your .sql file. Does it describe the necessary environment or maybe provide another .sql file to setup a suitable toy database? Or maybe there is a *.db file at the origin of your .sql?

Comment: Where did you get the .sql file from?

Comment: 12 days without  an answer to the comments. The question is unclear as it is and needs the requested information.